# How to solve RECV SSLv3 ALERT: fatal, bad_record_mac

Tags: apache, ssl, cas, certificate, sslhandshakeexception

Over the last few days I have tried to install a working CAS server (Jasig CAS) on Ubuntu 10.10. I installed Tomcat 6 and configured (server.xml) it for SSL port 8443:

```
<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector port="8443"
        maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="150"
        minSpareThreads="25"
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
        acceptCount="100"
        scheme="https"
        secure="true"
        clientAuth="false"
        SSLEnabled="true"
        SSLProtocol="SSLv3"
        SSLCertificateFile="/etc/ssl/certs/server_cert.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile="/etc/ssl/private/server_key.pem"
        SSLCACertificateFile="/etc/ssl/certs/ca_cert.pem"
        SSLCACertificatePath="/etc/ssl/certs"
        SSLPassword="password"
     />
```

server_cert.pem, server_key.pem are self-signed x509 certificates. Further, I created a x509v3 certificate for a windows test server (apache2 - xampp) (both servers are in the same LAN and have the IPs 10.0.0.*) . these certificate is installed in the java keystore (cacerts) which is located in the java directory. Since I had always problems with the "alternative subject name" in the client certificate I used an extended version of the openssl config file to create it.

The apache2 ssl config file looks as follows:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
....
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.2:443>
SSLEngine on
ServerName 10.0.0.2:443
#ServerAlias 10.0.0.2

DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs
SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3
SSLCertificateFile C:/xampp/ssl/certs/powercomputer_cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/xampp/ssl/private/powercomputer_key.pem
SSLCACertificateFile C:/xampp/ssl/certs/ca_cert.pem
</VirtualHost>
...
</IfModule>
```

SSL connections are working on both servers (tested by using IE and firefox).

Now comes the hard task. I used a module called phpCAS, programmed in php, on the windows machine to communicate with the CAS server. The module sends a callback url to the CAS server and the server sends a proxy ticket back etc. etc.

BUT I was not able to ensure a valid SSL handshake between both servers. openssl -s_client -connect... for both servers it did not show any errors so I debugged the complete SSL handshake (here is only the relevant part):

...

> *** ServerHelloDone
>
> *** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, SSLv3 http-apr-8443-exec-3, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 132 SESSION
>
> KEYGEN: PreMaster Secret: 0000: 03 00 78 96 8F EE D3 4A   2F A8 CC F8
>   F9 D7 2F CB  ..x....J/...../. 0010: 9E 3A 58 66 43 0E D5 49   3C 8A B0
>   3D 3F 2C 89 A0  .:XfC..I<..=?,.. 0020: BC E2 B2 12 F8 D9 55 73   F2 2C
>   1F CC 81 80 94 22  ......Us.,....." CONNECTION KEYGEN: Client Nonce:
>   0000: 4E D1 94 ED 32 7F FA 72   40 3C 43 C8 05 E2 62 D0 
>   N...2..r@
>   91 E2 D0 1C 90 3D 30 DD  ..n;W6.......=0. Master Secret: 0000: EB 25
>   F0 A2 A3 FF 37 06   BB 79 41 C5 E5 07 1C 64  .%....7..yA....d 0010: 77
>   66 A3 37 71 97 63 AF   DB A2 79 47 85 E2 9C 74  wf.7q.c...yG...t 0020:
>   5F 14 3D 26 57 E8 AD 9B   A1 7C AC 33 00 04 4A E0  _.=&W......3..J.
>   Client MAC write Secret: 0000: C9 20 BF A5 A6 2B C1 DA   A8 4E 93 E0
>   DE 76 06 53  . ...+...N...v.S Server MAC write Secret: 0000: 66 77 5A
>   3E BD E7 19 55   A4 80 1E E6 8A 9E 2A 5E  fwZ>...U......*^ Client
>   write key: 0000: 58 D1 29 38 13 D8 83 EF   4F BD 7A 18 C8 35 D7 B4 
>   X.)8....O.z..5.. Server write key: 0000: 3A 7B 6A 6E 66 E9 E1 42   A4
>   3C C3 19 D0 7F 21 FF  :.jnf..B.<....!. ... no IV used for this cipher
>
> http-apr-8443-exec-3, WRITE: SSLv3 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
>
> *** Finished verify_data:  { 71, 19, 125, 80, 118, 60, 64, 122, 243, 112, 45, 18, 254, 144, 12, 143, 221, 125, 10, 94, 15, 221, 122, 21,
>   90, 190, 76, 224, 224, 57, 67, 172, 228, 75, 181, 228 }
>
> *** http-apr-8443-exec-3, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 56 http-apr-8443-exec-3, 
>   READ: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
>
> http-apr-8443-exec-3, RECV SSLv3 ALERT:  fatal, bad_record_mac
>
> http-apr-8443-exec-3, called closeSocket() http-apr-8443-exec-3,
>
> handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert:
>
> bad_record_mac 2011-11-27 02:39:57,315 ERROR
>
> [org.jasig.cas.util.HttpClient] -
>
> bad_record_mac> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert:
>
> bad_record_mac at  sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)  at
>   ....

I did not find any solution in the last few days and I really do not have a clue what is the problem. btw I forced the use of SSLv3.

Thank you very much for any suggestions.